# asp.net mvc3 or mvc4 html helper is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I just started learning and exploring ASP.NET MVC 4.5 and I was trying to figure out `HtmlHelper`. Apparently, when I run the application on the browser I see  `<%= ViewData["greeting"] %> , world (from the view)!` but not the value of the helper `ViewData`. Either I am doing something wrong or maybe Visual Studio does not support `HtmlHelper`s or maybe you have to change the setting to make it work. I tried downloading updates but it didn't work either. I also tried to made new projects under .NET framework 3.5, 4, and 4.5  but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Here is part of `index.cshtml`.

```cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
        
<body>
  <h2>Home</h2>
  <%= ViewData["greeting"] %> , world (from the view)!
</body>
```

`homeController`:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
        
namespace PartyInvites_2.Controllers
{
    public class homeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /home/
        
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            ViewData["greeting"] = (hour < 12 ? "good morning" : "good evening");
        
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using razor or asp.net template? Razor syntax should be `@ViewData["greeting"]`

Comment: i think i am using razor template

Comment: thanks dude, its working , i think it was razor, thank you

Answer (score 0):

(This answer was taken from [@codingbiz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651897/asp-net-mvc3-or-mvc4-html-helper-is-not-working#comment25706364_17651897); I did not write this solution, but OP found it helpful)

> Are you using razor or asp.net template? Razor syntax should be `@ViewData["greeting"]`

According to OP, fixing the syntax worked. I believe this is how that would look:

```cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
        
<body>
  <h2>Home</h2>
  @ViewData["greeting"] , world (from the view)!
</body>
```